# Comparing plot variables with average results

Tags: r, ggplot2

Provided the [following dataframe](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=MLTKev3z) I have successfully been able to create the following plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

df = read.csv("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=MLTKev3z")

ggplot(df,
       aes(x = factor(Identificación.con.el.barrio),
           fill = Nombre.barrio)
) +
  geom_histogram(position="dodge") +
  ggtitle("¿Te identificas con tu barrio?") +
  labs(x="Grado de identificación con el barrio", fill="Barrios")
```

Resulting in the following plot:

[image]

However, I would like to add a new column with the average results per each observation for  "Grado" variable (with no stratification per neighborhood - aka"barrio"), so I would be able to compare each neighborhood result with the city's.

Could anyone help me in how to achieve that?

Comment: Can you clarify "the average results per each answer"? Do you want a bar for each Grado (1:4 and NA) showing the average across Barrio, or do you want another x-value labelled "average" with the average Grado per Barrio? (I'm guessing the former.)

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant, but works. Involves changing your original data around to make a frequency table, then adding group averages. This necessitates using geom_bar() in ggplot instead of geom_histogram(). Result is identical.

```
# Make a frequency table of your data
library('plyr')
df2 <- ddply(df, .(Barrio,Grado), summarise, Freq=length(Grado))

# Make a table of averages
avg <- data.frame(as.data.frame(table(df2$Grado)/3,stringsAsFactors=F))
names(avg)[1] <- "Grado"
avg$Barrio <- "Average"

# Combine the tables
df2 <- rbind(df2, avg)
df2$Grado <- as.character(df2$Grado)
df2[is.na(df2$Grado),"Grado"] <- "N/A"

# Plot using a barplot instead of a histogram
ggplot(df2, aes(x=Grado,y=Freq,fill=Barrio)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position=position_dodge()) +
  scale_x_discrete("Grado de identificación con el barrio") +
  scale_y_continuous("Count")
```

Note: I also changed your variable names to something simpler, hence the scale labels.

The result is this:

[image: New bar chart with averages]